# (Racket/Scheme) Subtraction yields result off by incredibly small margin

Tags: math, floating-point, lisp, scheme, precision

I'm currently messing around with "[How To Design Programs](http://www.htdp.org/)" - using Scheme/Racket; I've come across a really peculiar feature in the R5RS version of Scheme.

When conducting a simple subtraction, albeit using values with decimal point accurace, answers are minutely off what would be expected.

For example; given the following subtraction operation:

```
(- 5.00 4.90)
=> 0.09999999999999965
```

When one should surely be expecting a clean 0.10? Whole number subtraction works as expected;

```
> (- 5 4)
 => 1
> (- 5 4.9)
 => 0.09999999999999965
```

Take for example, **Exercise 3.1.1**:

> The next step is to make up examples for each of the functions. Determine how many attendees can afford a show at a ticket price of $3.00, $4.00, and $5.00. Use the examples to formulate a general rule that shows how to compute the number of attendees from the ticket price. Make up more examples if needed.

The rule in the example that was for every $0.10 taken off of the ticket prices, 15 more people would attend. So a quick function like this would work..

```
(define (attendees ticket-price)
  (+ 120 (* (/ (- 5.00 ticket-price) 0.10) 15)))
```

However, this returns the (rather annoying)..

```
> (attendance 4.90)
 => 134.99999999999994
```

So after trying the (pretty much identical) solution from the text book..

```
(define (attendance price)
  (+ (* (/ 15 .10) (- 5.00 price))
    120))
```

I got exactly the same error. Is this something specific with my local system? I'm pretty curious - in reality I could simply use some form of rounding to correct this; but I'd rather know why it's occurring first!

Apart from that, I advise anyone interested in Lisp to look at HTDP. It appears to be quite a gentle text from skimming it, very hands on. I do like SICP - but thats more of a long term thing; I seem to spend a good few days doing the reading, then the exercises, then catching up with lectures online. HTDP seems to be a bit more like '*Oh, I've got 15 minutes spare - I'll look at HTDP*'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Floating-point numbers are not always stored as the exact values you expect. See e.g. [The Perils of Floating Point](http://www.lahey.com/float.htm).

If you want exact calculations, you could use integer arithmetic in your case by storing the values in cents instead of dollars.

```
(define (attendees ticket-price-cents)
  (+ 12000 (* (/ (- 500 ticket-price-cents) 10) 1500)))
```

Comment: I figured it would be a floating point issue! I was just curious as to why I used the exact same implementation as the book did, and the results were different. I would never have guessed floating point issues were so apparent in something as 'high-level' as a lisp dialect; I thought it would've been a universal behaviour!

Comment: To clarify on this, just a bit: the difference in behaviors is not nondeterministic: it stems from the difference in how programs are "read", as I indicate in my answer.

Comment: And to make it more clear: in Racket, if you type `0.25`, it will read **exactly** if the underlying language level has been configured for it.  The Beginner Student Language level used in HTDP is designed to do this, as are the other student language levels.  Otherwise, in professional-level Racket (`#lang racket`), you write out exact decimals more explicitly like this: `#e0.25`.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the prior (correct) answer: the question you really should be asking is: "why doesn't this happen in other language levels?" To which the answer is: many of the other language levels interpret 5.03 as being an exact number (five and three hundredths) rather than as a floating-point number.

JFYI!